# CSS: table cell doesn't collapse when resizing image

Tags: css

I have a table defined as follows in HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="font-size:small;">
        <th colspan="2">Name</th>
        <th>Abbr.</th>
        <th style="width:100%;">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:5px;text-align:centered;width:48px;">
            <img src="..." style="max-width:32px" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;">Some Text</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Everything renders fine when the image size is 32px or smaller.  When the image is larger, it a resized to 32px as expected but the table cell remains at the original width.  For instance, if the original image is 100x100, the image is resized to 32x32 but the table cell is displayed with a width of 100px.

What am I missing so that the table cell will render with the correct width regardless of the original size of the image?

UPDATE
I updated the original markup to show the full table layout.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: I second @thirtydot - just tried with Firefox 4 and IE9 and couldn't recreate this.

Comment: I'm using IE8. You are correct that this problem doesn't occur with Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem in only IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtc5m/

To fix it in IE8, you can add [`table-layout: fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout).

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dtc5m/1/

---

After further discussion in the comments, the accepted solution turned out to be:

> wrap the `img` in a `div`, and give the
>   `div` a `width` equal to the `max-width` of
>   the `img`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtc5m/6

Comment: For some reason, when I add 'table-layout:fixed' to the table's style, now the first two columns overlap?  Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I've updated JSFiddle and it is doing the same thing. It appears that having a <th> element with 'width:100%;' is the root cause of the overlap. However, I want to have the last column 'push' the previous columns left so the last column 'fills' the remaining space to the right.

Comment: ..can you give me a link to the version you edited so I can also see `"the first two columns overlap"`?

Comment: It's because of your `<th style="width:100%;">&nbsp;</th>`. `table-layout: fixed` basically means "exactly use the widths I specify", and you're telling one column to take all the space. With that removed: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtc5m/5/

Comment: Yea but notice that the first three columns have additional width. I need them collapsed to their minimum sizes (including the first column which should have a fixed width). As it stands, the table is rendered with each column taking 25% of the width.

Comment: I wish you'd have included your full table in your original question, because if you had I wouldn't have suggested `table-layout: fixed`. Let's try a new solution: wrap the `img` in a `div`, and give the `div` a `width` equal to the `max-width` of the `img`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtc5m/6/

Comment: Yea,sorry. I continued working on the page after the 1st post while waiting for responses and added the header stuff before seeing your reply with the table-layout suggestion.  The <div> approach appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This page displays correctly in Google Chrome but not in IE.

The usual reason for this is not setting the doctype, when I added it in, I got a correct display.

for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:100%;'>
    <tr>
        <td style='padding:5px;text-align:center;width:48px;'>
            <img src='...' style='max-width:32px;' />
        </td>
        <td style='padding:5px;white-space:nowrap;'>Some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information see http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have the following in my markup: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: As I noted above, you are correct that the page renders correctly in Chrome.  It appears the problem is limited to IE 8.